# Как заменить часть элементов из строки в kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Есть строка в виде **+7 (960) 454 343 88**. Каким образом можно заменить часть элементов на символ **#**, чтобы по итогу получилось **+7 (960) ## ##3 88** ?

Метод *replaceRange* заменяет все элементы одним символом с учетом пробелов

Comment: _Метод replaceRange заменяет все элементы одним символом с учетом пробелов_ - как раз то, что надо, не?

Comment: Получается так, что он все элементы заменяет одним и получается +7 (960)#3 88, удаляя ещё и пробел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал более общий вариант

```
    fun String.replaceCharsByCondition(
        with: Char,
        startIndexInclusive: Int,
        endIndexExclusive: Int,
        condition: (Char) -> Boolean
    ): String {
        val newStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        forEachIndexed { i, char ->
            if (condition(char) && i >= startIndexInclusive && i < endIndexExclusive) {
                newStringBuilder.append(with)
            } else {
                newStringBuilder.append(char)
            }
        }
        return newStringBuilder.toString()
    }
```

Пример вызова для Вашего случая:

```
        val phone = "+7 (960) 454 343 88"
        text.text = phone.replaceCharsByCondition(
            with = '#',
            startIndexInclusive = 9,
            endIndexExclusive = 15,
            condition = { it.isDigit() }
        )
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошее решение

Answer (score 0):

Применим грязный хак под названием... не знаю, под каким названием, просто применим без названия:

```
val new_text = text.replaceRange(9, 15, "## ##")
```